# A portable, std::string-like string class which is not std::string

Tags: string, c++11, compatibility, stdstring, vstring

For various (C++11 std::string-change-related) reasons I would like to use a non-std::string string class in some places in my C++11-ish code, which need to be agreeable with several versions of several C++ compilers.

Now, I don't really mind whether my strings behave in pre-C++11-style or post-C++11 way; and I don't care about performance either. I just want a nice reliable string class which under no circumstances gives me errors involving `std::__cxx11::string` and other such voodoo.

What are my options? Can I/should I replicate some single compiler's implementation in my own header files? Is GCC's vstring an option? Something else?

Comment: What qualifies as "string-like"? You say you don't care about the differences -- part of the reason that C++11 made the change is that the new version is much more thread-safe. Can you clarify what it is you concretely want? Do you just want it to be convertible to both types of strings? Why can't you just convert between the two types at whatever boundaries are appropriate in your project, why do you need a third type of string. Why can't you just recompile all code and related libraries at C++11 using the new string type, and forget the whole mess.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: Let's say that it implements `std::string`'s methods. Or if I wanted to be more modest - can be used as a map key and has the equicalent of `.c_str()`. Thread safety not a must.

Comment: I think all of the possibilities you mention are options? The question doesn't contain enough info to eliminate any of them afaict. You could certainly role your own that can be used as a map key and has `.c_str()` in 5 minutes or less.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Or really, inherit or own a `std::vector<char>` and make `.c_str()` insert a `\0` at the end of it if missing.  Forward `operator<` to it, and done.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T>
struct crappy_string {
  mutable std::vector<T> buffer;
  T const* c_str() const {
    if (buffer.empty() || buffer.back())
      buffer.push_back(0);
    return buffer.data();
  }
  friend bool operator<( crappy_string const& lhs, crappy_string const& rhs ) {
    lhs.c_str(); rhs.c_str(); // ensure null terminator in both
    return lhs.buffer < rhs.buffer;
  }    
};
```

This satisfies the minimal requirements you gave in the comments.

Comment: That would only work for ordered maps. But point taken. I guess I shouldn't have given up on all those methods in the comments, that wasn't good bargaining :-(